# Dreaded "psql: could not connect to server: No such file" error with Homebrew/OSX

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I've just restarted OSX (Sierra 10.12.6) and when I try to run `psql` (which previously worked fine) I get the dreaded:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Trying `brew services restart postgresql` does not help, and `brew services start postgresql` claims the service is already running.

Yet `ps auxw | grep postgres` reveals no Postgres processes are running. Has Homebrew got confused?

`which psql` shows `/usr/local/bin/psql`.

Here's what I've tried...

`psql -h localhost` makes no difference.

I've run `brew uninstall --force postgresql` followed by `brew install postgresql`, which makes no difference. I've also tried doing the same after a `brew doctor` and `brew update`, which again makes no difference.

I've seen advice to delete the `postmaster.pid` file, but there is no such file in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`. There also doesn't appear to be a `server.log` file in that directory.

Running `locate PGSQL.5432` shows no files.

I am the owner of the `/usr/local/var/postgres` directory, with `drwxr-xr-x` permissions.

It's possible I might have installed KyngChaos postgres at some point in the past.

I've checked the .plist file indicated in the output of `brew services list` (`~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`), it shows the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm very keen not to have to delete all my postgres databases if possible, because I'm currently in a remote location with nowhere to back them up!

Comment: if you are completely sure postgres is not running, rename `postmaster.pid` from `$PGDATA` and try starting it again

Comment: Try starting manually, `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: Try checking `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` (as shown in the plist).

Comment: By now, you should have some sort of answer of what you did, to solve your situation?